# What was Sebastian's fate after the events of the show?

Tags: babylon-5, shadows-babylon-5, vorlons

Sebastian was introduced in B5 S2, E21, *Comes the Inquisitor*, after being summoned by Kosh to make sure Delann is acting for the right reasons; she is also warned this test will place her life in danger.

> The man introduces himself as Sebastian, and he did live in London in
> the late 19th century until the Vorlons took him in and showed him
> things that made him the way he is now. He has been brought out of
> stasis by the Vorlons so he can perform a test uniquely suited to him.
> He then demands to get to work.

At the end of the episode it is revealed that Sebastian is

> actually Jack the Ripper, drafted into service by the Vorlons, and kept in stasis when he’s not needed.

What happened to Sebastian, and those non-Vorlon wards in their custody after the events of the show? Specifically after

> the Vorlons left the Galaxy at the end of the Shadow War in S4 E6, *Into the Fire*? Was he brought with the Vorlons beyond the Galaxy? Did the humans and Minbari who finally were able to enter Vorlons space in the year 1,002,261, find a stasis pod with Sebastian suspended inside?

What is his ultimate fate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no definitive statement about his fate after this episode. However, Sebastian did express a hope that the interrogation of Delenn would be his last work for the Vorlons, and that he would be permitted to die:

> "I have done four hundred years of penance and service, a job for which they said I was ideally suited. Now, perhaps, they will finally let me die."